# how to write test class for global class

Tags: unit-test

Here is my code

```
global class Rforce_W2CSchema_CLS{

global class Casedetails{
    webservice String priority,emailOptIn,description,licenseNumber,suppliedPhone,city,postalCode,address,lastName,firstName,comAgreement,
               state,vin,dealer,language,caseFrom,detail,subject,cellPhone,company,title,caseIDBIR;           
    webservice List<CaseAttachments> attachmentDetails;
    webservice String country,suppliedEmail,type,origin,subType,subSource,caseBrand,dealerAfterSalesPostalCode;
    webservice Date firstRegistration,dateOfPurchase;
    webservice String customerExperience,reasonOfReturn,problemSolved,brandRecommendation,caseNumber,buyAgainIntention,renaultContactTitle,renaultContactFirstName,renaultContactLastName,renaultContactEmail;  
    webservice integer guarantyCode,kilometer; 



}
global class CaseAttachments{
    webservice Blob attachmentBody;
    webservice String attachmentName;
    webservice String attachmentContentType;
} 

}
```

Even though i am calling it from a test class , not even a single line is covered.
Test class code

```
@isTest
public class Rforce_W2CwithAttachmentService_Test{
static testMethod void createcasewithattachment(){
    Country_Info__c ctr = new Country_Info__c (Name = 'France', Country_Code_2L__c = 'FR', Language__c = 'Français', Case_RecordType__c='FR_Case_RecType');
    insert ctr;

    List<Rforce_W2CSchema_CLS.CaseAttachments> attach= new List<Rforce_W2CSchema_CLS.CaseAttachments>();
    Rforce_W2CSchema_CLS.CaseAttachments att=new Rforce_W2CSchema_CLS.CaseAttachments();
    att.attachmentBody=Blob.valueof('sdfadfs');
    att.attachmentName='test';
    att.attachmentContentType='doc';
    attach.add(att);

    Rforce_W2CSchema_CLS.Casedetails casedetail=new Rforce_W2CSchema_CLS.Casedetails();
    casedetail.Priority='High';
    casedetail.emailOptIn='True';
    casedetail.description='test web service';
    casedetail.licenseNumber='asdfasf';
    casedetail.suppliedPhone='455656';
    casedetail.City='France';
    casedetail.postalCode='605004';
    casedetail.address='test';
    casedetail.lastName='lname';
    casedetail.firstName='fname';
    casedetail.comAgreement='true';
    casedetail.state='Paris';
    casedetail.vin='12345678912345';
    casedetail.dealer='test';
    casedetail.suppliedEmail='test123@gmail.com';
    casedetail.country='France';
    casedetail.language='French';
    casedetail.caseFrom='Customer';
    casedetail.detail='';
    casedetail.subType='';
    casedetail.type='Complaint';
    casedetail.subSource='RENAULT SITE';
    casedetail.caseBrand='Renault';
    casedetail.origin='RENAULT SITE';
    casedetail.subject='test';
    casedetail.cellPhone='3454';
    casedetail.company='dfgdf';
    casedetail.title='Mr.';
    casedetail.attachmentdetails=attach;
    Test.startTest();
    Rforce_W2CwithAttachmentService.createCaseAndAttachment(casedetail);        
    Test.stopTest();
}
}
```

Comment: could you please post your class again.It doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: This is a webservices that you're trying to test. You need to create a mock for it. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_testing.htm. Also check out the Trailhead Integration Module.